# How long can tofu be kept in the fridge after it is opened?

Tags: tofu

How long can tofu be kept in the fridge after its opened? Are there any ways to extend the shelf life of tofu, either before or after opening the package? Can tofu be frozen so that it keeps longer? Does firm or soft tofu last longer in the fridge?

Comment: Tofu can definitely be frozen for extended periods of time; doing so will _dramatically_ change its texture. I regularly throw silken tofu in the freezer just for this reason; what comes out is much more dense and chewy, closer to seitan.

Comment: Despite not having a full answer, I can tell you that after opening it, keeping it submerged in water and changing the water every couple of days helps to prolong its shelf life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, tofu can be kept in the fridge (in it's original packaging) for at least a week, and probably up to two. Once it's been removed from the packaging any that's left over will need to be kept in a container and submerged in water. This should last about a week but probably not much longer. I freeze my tofu regularly. Sometimes I'll buy more than I need and keep one package in the fridge and the rest of it in the freezer. It should last as long as you need it to in the freezer, so long as you aren't intending to keep it for a year or more. Once it starts getting a bit slimy, it's time to throw it out.